# Python liburl grab site content with language

Tags: python, urllib

I want to grab some content from the site www.gyte.edu.tr site language is in Turkish but when you click a lang choose button on site with the address www.gyte.edu.tr?cl=2 it becomes in English. I want my code to visit http://www.gyte.edu.tr/kategori/54/9/laboratories.aspx? address and grab all the laboratory links and than visit all laboratory pages and grab information from those pages. With my code below, it grabs information in Turkish but not in English.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib.urlopen("http://www.gyte.edu.tr?cl=2")
linkler = urllib.urlopen("http://www.gyte.edu.tr?cl=2/kategori/54/9/laboratories.aspx")
site = linkler.read()
linkler.close()
link_list = []

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(site)
a_text = soup1.find("div","block news-area")

for link in a_text.find_all('a'):
    link_list.append(link.get('href'))
for l in link_list:
    s = urllib.urlopen(l)
    s1 = s.read()   
    s.close()
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(s1)
    soup3 = soup3.table
    soup3 = str(soup3)
    f = open("table.html", 'a')
    #  write the data
for data in soup3:
    f.write(data)
```

So how can I grab content in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're setting a cookie, so the language choice persists across sessions.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
#Sets language to english and saves cookie in Session s
s.get('http://www.gyte.edu.tr/?cl=2')
#Page in english
r = s.get("http://www.gyte.edu.tr/kategori/54/9/laboratories.aspx")
```

more about requests.Session()

```
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/
```